# How to fix the repetitive outputs from multiprocessing a method?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to run a Classifier model on top of an OD Model (used for localizing objects). To decrease the latency, I used multiprocessing for both OD as well as Classifier model. The output is correct but I am getting repetitive results.

I have a machine with 8 cores and so I am multiprocessing with `pool=mp.Pool(8)`
I am using `map_async` and have an iterable as the list of image paths.
To get the results as list I am using `.get()`.

In the starting I didn't implement `pool.join()` after `pool.close()`, which I identified after going through a few sites. The error in output I am getting is because of the `chunksize` I am passing to the `pool.map_async()`. The number of repetitions of the same output is same as the chunksize. But according to my understanding of chunksize, it should just create batches of size same as chunksize and pass each batch to one process.

```
return_stuff_classifier=[]

def label_it(image_path):
    file_name = image_path
    image_name=image_path.split('/')[-1]
    frame_id=image_name.split('_')[0]
    object_id=image_name.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
    label="gt"
    result="0.86" #Here I have explicitly mentioned this, not to go through the
                  #classifier model prediction
    return_stuff_classifier.append((frame_id,object_id,label,result))
    return return_stuff_classifier

def multiprocessor():
    m_class = mp.Manager()
    queue_class = m_class.Queue()
    pool_class=mp.Pool(8)

    # Here cropped_image_no 24 -> chunk_size_class=3
    chunk_size_class=round(cropped_images_no/8)

    results_class=pool_class.map_async(label_it,cropped_images,chunk_size_class).get()
    #label_it is the method to be multiprocessed
    #cropped_images is the list of all image paths to be multiprocessed

    pool_class.close()
    pool_class.join()
    final_results.append(results_class)
```

Output:

```
[[['443', '10', 'ugt', '0.85964435'],
  ['443', '11', 'ugut', '0.48011008'],
  ['443', '4', 'gut', '0.50242084']],
 [['443', '10', 'ugt', '0.85964435'],
  ['443', '11', 'ugut', '0.48011008'],
  ['443', '4', 'gut', '0.50242084']],
 [['443', '10', 'ugt', '0.85964435'],
  ['443', '11', 'ugut', '0.48011008'],
  ['443', '4', 'gut', '0.50242084']],
 [['443', '2', 'ugut', '0.8623834'],
  ['443', '6', 'gt', '0.95684755'],
  ['443', '1', 'gut', '0.683893']],
 [['443', '2', 'ugut', '0.8623834'],
  ['443', '6', 'gt', '0.95684755'],
  ['443', '1', 'gut', '0.683893']],
 [['443', '2', 'ugut', '0.8623834'],
  ['443', '6', 'gt', '0.95684755'],
  ['443', '1', 'gut', '0.683893']]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[[['443', '10', 'ugt', '0.85964435'],
  ['443', '11', 'ugut', '0.48011008']
  ['443', '4', 'gut', '0.50242084']],
 [['443', '2', 'ugut', '0.8623834'],
  ['443', '6', 'gt', '0.95684755'],
  ['443', '1', 'gut', '0.683893']]]
```

Comment: You didn't provide a [mre], and when I made up one of my own, I couldn't repeat the results you say you're getting. Suggest you provide your own runnable code that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you @matineau for replying. The problem I faced was due to the chunksize argument in the pool.map_async() method. As soon as I remove that argument problem is being solved. But I want to know if there is any way to solve this problem with chunksize too. And why this problem arised even when pool.join() is called.

Comment: The filename was - './<image_directory_path>/frame_1.jpg' and the list indexing is according to this notation.

Comment: I understood what you were saying with regards to chunksize — and did the same thing. Will attempt to try it again with the code you added.

Comment: Thank you.. please let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks to your update, I'm now able to reproduce the repetition problem...so am now able to try to figure out the cause (and hopefully a solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is the fact that you have the `label_it()` function append a result to the `return_stuff_classifier` list each time it is executed and then return the entire list — thereby returning a value that has accumulated the results of previous calls. The number of times this occurs is controlled by the `chunksize`.

Fortunately that's easy to fix — just return the tuple you were appending to the list. If you do that, there's no longer a need to have the list at all.

Note I had to added an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard to the code so it would work on my computer running Windows because child processes are created differently on it than they are on unix-like OSs. It should still work on them, so doing so it portable. The need to do this is in the documentation in a subsection titled *Safe importing of main module* in the `multiprocessing` module's [Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines).

Another change made was to move the `get()` call to after the `pool_class.join()`, because by then all the child processes have ended. Doing it wasn't required in this case because the main process had effectively nothing further to do, but it's the canonical way to retrieve results from `map_async()` — probably because it would allow the main process to concurrently perform other tasks, if it had any to do.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from pprint import pprint

cropped_images = [f'./image_directory_path/frame_{i}.jpg' for i in range(1, 25)]
#return_stuff_classifier = []  # No longer needed.

def label_it(image_path):
    file_name = image_path
    image_name = image_path.split('/')[-1]
    frame_id = image_name.split('_')[0]
    object_id = image_name.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
    label = "gt"
    result = "0.86" # Here I have explicitly mentioned this, not to go through the
                    # classifier model prediction

#    return_stuff_classifier.append((frame_id, object_id, label, result))
#    return return_stuff_classifier

    return (frame_id, object_id, label, result)  # Just return the results.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def multiprocessor():
        m_class = mp.Manager()
        queue_class = m_class.Queue()
        pool_class = mp.Pool(8)
        final_results = []

        # Here cropped_image_no == 24 -> chunk_size_class=3
        chunk_size_class = round(len(cropped_images) / 8)
        print(f'{chunk_size_class=}')

        results_class = pool_class.map_async(label_it, cropped_images, chunk_size_class)
        # label_it is the method to be multiprocessed
        # cropped_images is the list of all image paths to be multiprocessed

        pool_class.close()
        pool_class.join()
        final_results.append(results_class.get())

        pprint(final_results)

    multiprocessor()
```

Here's what prints showing there are now no repetitions:

```
chunk_size_class=3
[[('frame', '1', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '2', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '3', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '4', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '5', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '6', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '7', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '8', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '9', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '10', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '11', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '12', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '13', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '14', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '15', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '16', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '17', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '18', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '19', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '20', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '21', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '22', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '23', 'gt', '0.86'),
  ('frame', '24', 'gt', '0.86')]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is solved. The error I was making was appending the result before pool.join() as you rightly pointed out. Thank you so much. :)